# Orbeon 3.9 request without javascript support

Tags: orbeon

I need to make a request to orbeon forms without javascript support but it returns message "Your browser does not appear to support JavaScript. You may want to try one of the following"

I need this to print PDF with pd4ml. In orbeon 3.7 I got that message but the form was shown at the botton. In orbeon 3.9 I get the message but the form is not being show.

```
Is there a way to get the behavior of orbeon 3.7?
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason the form is hidden is that it has an HTML class on the `<form>` element, `xforms-initially-hidden`, which initially hides the form content until JavaScript code has run. If JavaScript is disabled, that class never goes away and the form remains hidden.

If you override that CSS class to make the form initially visible, or if you remove the class altogether, things should work.

Comment: Done! Thank you very much! I make it work adding this css.

.xforms-noscript-panel {
    border: 4px solid #FF6600;
    margin: 1em;
    padding: 0.5em;
    width: auto;
    display: none !important; 
    }

.xforms-initially-hidden{
 display: none !important; 
}

.xforms-layout-nospan{
 display: block !important; 
}

Comment: Hi I test it on a browser without javascript and it works fine. But when I try to render with pd4ml it does not work as orbeon 3.7. The styles are not being found by pd4ml. Is there a behavior change on this?. Im using the theme-plain.xsl. If you have a clue on this I will thank you in advanced.

Comment: I don't know pd4ml. It might depend on how pd4ml resolves access to CSS in the file. Maybe you can check to see what requests pd4ml is trying to do to retrieve CSS.

Comment: Really don't know because it's not open source. But using theme-plain.xsl form orbeon 3.7 seems to do the job. Not really sure why or how but anyway. Thank you very much!